# How do I provide a collection of elements to a custom attached property?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I found a few examples online, and a few questions and answers here, but I just can't get it to work. I need a custom attached property that can take one or more target elements. For example...

```
<ListView>
    <dd:MyDragDrop.DropBorders>
        <Binding ElementName="brdOne"/>
        <Binding ElementName="brdTwo"/>
        <Binding ElementName="brdThree"/>
    </dd:MyDragDrop.DropBorders>
</ListView>
```

I've also had a play with using a MultiBinding instead, but with no luck.

```
<ListView>
    <dd:MyDragDrop.DropBorders>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource multi}">
            <Binding ElementName="brdOne"/>
            <Binding ElementName="brdTwo"/>
            <Binding ElementName="brdThree"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </dd:MyDragDrop.DropBorders>
</ListView>
```

I'll elaborate more later when I have time, but in the meantime.. is there a 'correct' way to do this? It feels like it should be more simple than I'm making it!

FYI, this is the attached property I'm playing with. Totally an experiment right now, so no polish at all, and largely a result of trying different solutions from different online solutions.

```
public class BorderCollection : List<Border>
{

}

public static readonly DependencyProperty DropBordersProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("DropBorders", typeof(BorderCollection), typeof(MyDragDrop));

public static BorderCollection GetDropBorders(ListView listView)
{
    var collection = (BorderCollection)listView.GetValue(DropBordersProperty);
    if (collection == null)
    {
        collection = new BorderCollection();
        listView.SetValue(DropBordersProperty, collection);
    }
    return collection;
}

public static void SetDropBorders(ListView listView, BorderCollection borders)
{
    listView.SetValue(DropBordersProperty, borders);

    foreach (Border border in borders)
    {
        border.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You must not do anything else than GetValue and SetValue in the CLR wrappers of a dependency property. This also applies to the Get and Set method of attached properties. See [XAML Loading and Dependency Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613563(v=vs.100).aspx) for details.

Comment: Yep, what @Clemens said. If you need to do anything when the property is set, you have to specify a PropertyChanged callback method using `PropertyMetadata` on your DependencyProperty definition. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertychangedcallback(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: (Oh, and using `PropertyMetadata` you can also specify the property's default value, which you are now doing in the GetDropBorders, to no avail)

Comment: @almulo But note that you shouldn't usually set the default values of reference types - especially collections - by property metadata. All instances of the DependencyObject would operate on the same collection instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it working using an `IMultiValueConverter` like this:

```
public class BorderCollectionConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var borderCollection = new BorderCollection();
        borderCollection.AddRange(values.OfType<Border>());

        return borderCollection;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And using it in XAML just like in your example:

```
    <Border Height="20" Name="border1" Background="Blue" />
    <Border Height="20" Name="border2" Background="Green" />
    <Border Height="20" Name="border3" Background="Yellow" />
    <Control>
        <dd:MyDragDrop.DropBorders>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource borderCollectionConverter}">
                <Binding ElementName="border1" />
                <Binding ElementName="border3" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </dd:MyDragDrop.DropBorders>
    </Control>
```

The main difference is in how I declared the `DependencyProperty`, using the advices given in the comments of your question (no code in getter or setter, and use metadata instead to define a property changed callback):

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DropBordersProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("DropBorders", typeof(BorderCollection), typeof(MyDragDrop),
    new PropertyMetadata(null, DropBordersChanged));

public static BorderCollection GetDropBorders(DependencyObject listView)
{
    return (BorderCollection)listView.GetValue(DropBordersProperty);
}

public static void SetDropBorders(DependencyObject listView, BorderCollection borders)
{
    listView.SetValue(DropBordersProperty, borders);
}

public static void DropBordersChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var border in (BorderCollection)e.NewValue)
        border.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
}
```

And the final result...

[image: Example showing two Borders with red background and one with green background]

Comment: Thanks almulo - I'll try this today and see what happens!

Comment: I'm confused. I literally copied/pasted your code (and added the converter as an app resource) and I'm getting a XAML error saying that "The value "System.Windows.Data.MultiBinding" is not of type "System.Windows.Controls.Border" and cannot be used in this generic collection. Prameter name: value" .. and I'm not entirely sure what that means!

Comment: Don't set `new BorderCollection()` as default value in property metadata. The dependency property registration is static, and hence done only once. Multiple DependencyObject instance will therefore operate on *the same* default collection instance, unless you explicitly set a property value.

Comment: Thanks. I've removed the default. But I still get the same XAML error in the designer (whether it's there or not). However, it does actually run! Would love to get rid of that XAML error though. Failing to wrap my head around what it's complaining about. It's as though it's not taking the converter into account, so it's expecting a collection of Borders in the dependency property and not a MultiBinding?

Comment: Don't know if this clarifies things, but if I replace the converter with a Border element, it's happy, because that's what it's expecting. But it complains when I try to put a converter in there that should resolve to one or more borders.

Comment: @Clemens You're right! Totally forgot about that, I'll edit to avoid problems (after all, initialization is not really needed for this example).

Comment: @MattWinward That sounds like the designer and XAML parser acting up... Which version of the Framework are you using?

Comment: By the way, although I've marked your answer as *the* answer (it answers the question perfectly, and it works). I've since realised that it might be neater to have an "IsDragSource" property on the ListView, and "IsDroptarget" properties on the Borders. I'd then just have to manage static dictionaries of drag sources and their potential targets. This would mean that I can do away with the converter altogether!

Comment: Using existing functionality trumps any gimmick, for sure! Glad you found a better way to do this

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do following:

```
<ListView>
    <dd:MyDragDrop.DropBorders>
        <Border Style="{StaticResource brdOneStyle}"/>
        <Border Style="{StaticResource brdTwoStyle}"/>
        <Border Style="{StaticResource brdThreeStyle}"/>
    </dd:MyDragDrop.DropBorders>
</ListView>
```

I don't recommend you to specify DropBorders using binding, because Border is UIElement and UIElement can be in visual tree only once. If you had multiple listview using the same instace of Border element, you could get runtime error. If you want to reuse the border, use styles instead.

Comment: however, MultiBinding as show in your post will work, if the converter returns instance of BorderCollection

Comment: Thanks Liero. However, the Border elements are not members of my ListView; they are outside of it, hence the bindings with TargetElement. The UI will likely consist of a ListView on the left, and a vertical stack of Borders to drop ListView items into.

Answer (score 0):

Your `BorderCollection` is a `List` of `Border` elements, however, you are trying to use a collection of `Binding` elements instead.

```
<dd:MyDragDrop.DropBorders>
    <Binding ElementName="brdOne"/>
    <Binding ElementName="brdTwo"/>
    <Binding ElementName="brdThree"/>
</dd:MyDragDrop.DropBorders>
```

Remember, `Binding` elements **are not** `Border` elements. Your `DropBorders` collection expects a list of `Border`. Like this:

```
<dd:MyDragDrop.DropBorders>
    <Border ... />

    ...
</dd:MyDragDrop.DropBorders>
```

Consider changing your `BorderCollection` to inherit `List<Binding>` instead. You can then use your collection of bindings to get the borders in the collection.

Comment: changing your `BorderCollection` to inherit `List<Binding>` will not work well: 1. binding won't be evaluated; 2. binding won't be set to a framework element, so they cannot traverse visual three and use DataContext, RelativeSource or ElementName. It would be totally useless